# Open a PDF in a new window of the browser with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, http, pdf, browser, get

I'm new to angular js and I wish to open a PDF document in a new window of the browser after pressing a button.

I make a GET request with `$http.get()` at front end, at backend there is a Java rest service that respond to the GET and generates a PDF. I wish to open this PDF on the browser.

If is not possible to open the PDF in this way then at least open any PDF with AngularJs, how could I do this?

```
@GET
@Path("/printPdf")
public Response printService(){

//generates the pdf

File reportFile = new File(filePath);
String name = reportName + "." + "pdf";
ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(new     TemporaryFileInputStream(reportFile));
response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name);
response.header("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
response.header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "x-filename");
response.header("x-filename", name);

return response.build();
}
```

this is what there is at backend to generate the response in the rest service.

Comment: Same way you would with any pdf...this is not angular specific. What specific problem are you having?

Comment: send url back and open that url

Comment: I have tried with $window.open('pdf_file') but its not working

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you had something like this:

```
var myPdfUrl = 'something'
$http.get(myPdfUrl);
```

Do this instead:

```
var myPdfUrl = 'something'  
$window.open(myPdfUrl);
```

If instead you have something like this:

```
$http
    .get(generatePdfUrl)
    .then(function(data){
        //data is link to pdf
    });
```

Do this:

```
$http
    .get(generatePdfUrl)
    .then(function(data){
        //data is link to pdf
        $window.open(data);
    });
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but its not working seems I'm doing something wrong at backend in the rest service, i just edited and posted the code of it. Is there something wrong?

Comment: Thanks Mathew Berg , I made it work changing this line of code      response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name) to response.header("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + name) because it was asking me to download instead of open the file in a new window.

Comment: Thanks but it's actually ` window.open(data);`

Comment: @SbonisoMarcusNzimande This is angular, you inject the $window so you can mock tests.

Answer (score 17):

Maybe this can help,in the case of you have something like this :

```
$http.get('generatePdfUrl')
  .then(function (data) {     // data is your url
      var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
      var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  });
```

Then use your service in controller and do

```
$window.open(fileURL);
```

Comment: pop-up blocker interfer in chrome