# How to open a stored doc/pdf through angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

How do I open a document\pdf that is stored in my system through an angularjs project on a button click? It is fine even if it is opened outside the application with any document viewer.

Comment: It is not clear whether you saved as a file or into database
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053212/open-a-pdf-in-a-new-window-of-the-browser-with-angularjs
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781927/how-to-read-pdf-stream-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

```
   ng-click="window.open('full path & file name for pdf')"
```

should do it.

You can also use:

```
    ng-click="window.open('full path & file name for pdf',_blank)"
```

to open in a new tab.