# pdf document opening issue with angularjs mobile app. with cordova build

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, pdf, jquery-mobile

Currently i am working on opening pdf document in angularjs w.r.t. desktop/ mobile also.
i have followed this ref.:
[Open a PDF in a new window of the browser with angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053212/open-a-pdf-in-a-new-window-of-the-browser-with-angularjs)
there similar implementation i have done :
code is as follows

```
**$http.get('generatePdfUrl')
  .then(function (data) {     // data is your url
      var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
      var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  });**
```

even i have applied responsetype : 'arraybuffer' as well,
in the angularjs web application this url points to 
blob://http://localhost:8080/126gyesdfsdfadjf,
**its is opening pdf document properly with window.open(fileURL),**
but the same is not working for the angularjs mobile application using cordova build,
there application url points out to blob:file///126gyesdfsdfadjf,
but unable to open pdf document,
can anybody have suggestions on this.
regars,
vasu.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you need to install a plugin for opening the pdf document.

```
function writePDFToFile(fileName, data){
        try{
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory, function(directoryEntry){
                directoryEntry.getFile(fileName, { create: true }, function(fileEntry){
                    fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter){
                        fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e){
                            cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory + fileName, 'application/pdf',{
                                error: function(e){
                                    console.log('Error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
                                },
                                success: function () {
                                    console.log('file opened successfully');
                                }
                            });
                        };

                        fileWriter.onerror = function(e){
                            alert(e);
                        };

                        var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                        fileWriter.write(blob);

                    }, function onerror(e){
                        alert(e);
                    });
                }, function onerror(e){

                    alert(e);
                });
            },function onerror(e){            
                alert(e);
            });
        }catch(e){
            alert(e);
        }
    }
```

above implementation worked for me.
Check this [link](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileOpener2/) for plugin.

Comment: but in my case, i have url : blob:file://fcxysdjfsjdkfj, this is not working for me, & so it returns filenot found

Comment: Hi all cordova pdf document opening  wroks fine w.r.t. ios devices & i am facing issues with android devices, plz let me know if any suggestions, as per my requirement i need to open pdf document with any existing third party apps.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. I'm getting json response as ArrayBuffer and I'm passing the same in th writePDFToFile function as 'data' argument. This is a working code in android.

Comment: thanks for info. this is working superb in android devices.